# ComboBox member path in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a function in my WPF project that connects to mySQL database and fetches all the information in the table Clients.

I'm creating a binding list of type client which will have as a value the client ID and as a display the Client Name.

Is there any easy way to set the display member path to the two columns, the name and number of the client concatenated together directly and easily, without the need of much more code? As in without the need to create a table and add a column which joins these two fields together, and set the display to be the new columns name.

```
public void GetClientsList()
    {
    BindingList<client> Clients = new BindingList<client>();

    try
    {
        using (smsdbmsEntities context = new smsdbmsEntities())
        {
            var query = (from r in context.clients.AsEnumerable()
                         select r).ToList();

            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                Clients.Add(x);
            }

            cb_ClientList.ItemsSource = Clients;

            cb_ClientList.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            cb_ClientList.SelectedValuePath = "CID";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot get Clients! " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always use a `string` property on your `client` object that is get-only and just returns the concatenated value? Then, just set your display member path to use this, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (use NotMapped attribute so you don't have to create a column in database if its your model class).

```
[NotMapped]
public string ClientInfo
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, NumberOfClients); }
}
```

Bind ClientInfo as your `DisplayMemberPath`property.